# Using Automapper - how do I map from this ICollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using entity framework and automapper for the first time. I am lost. I have a class containing an `ICollection` of another class which I wish to map:

Here are my classes:

```
public class BaseEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car : BaseEntity {
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CarPart> CarParts { get; set; }
}

public class Part : BaseEntity {
    public string PartName { get; set; }
}

public class CarPart : BaseEntity {
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public Part Part { get; set; }
}
```

and then my DTO:

```
public class CarDTO {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CarPart> CarParts { get; set; }
}
```

and my mapping configuration profile contains:

```
CreateMap<Car, CarDTO> ();
```

and then in my controller I use:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
return _mapper.Map<Car, CarDTO>(car);
```

When I hit the API I get the following error:

```
Destination Member:
CarParts
 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
CarPart -> Part
Entities.CarPart -> Entities.Part
```

What changes do I need to make to fix this?
Thank-you.

Edit:
The following is all in StartUp.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles));
}
```

**Edit #2:**
Changing the scope of this a little bit. I changed CarDTO to

```
public class CarDTO {
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

and added the following DTO:

```
 public class PartDTO
    {
        public int PartId { get; set; }
        public string PartName { get; set; }
    }
```

and edited my mapping configuration profile to

```
  public MappingProfiles () {
    
            CreateMap<Car, CarDTO> ()
.ForMember(dest => dest.CarId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember (dest => dest.Parts, opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom (src => src.CarParts.Select (x => x.Part
                    )));
    
            CreateMap<Part, PartDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PartId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        }
```

which returns this:

```
{
    "carId": 8,
    "make": "some make",
    "model": "some model",
    "year": 2001,
    "parts": [
        {
            "partName": "Fully sick Wheels",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "partName": "Mad Engine",
            "id": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I change this to:

```
{
    "carId": 8,
    "make": "some make",
    "model": "some model",
    "year": 2001,
    "parts": [
        {
            "partName": "Fully sick Wheels",
            "partId": 3
        },
        {
            "partName": "Mad Engine",
            "partId": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the mapping registrations you use?

Comment: Not reproducible for me with the provided information: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tvr9DM. Did you even check if the minimal example gave the same exception?

Comment: Make sure you have registered the mapping.

Comment: Hi @Woody,what is your version of automapper and asp.net core?It could work well in my projejct.

Comment: .Net version is 3.1.4 and austomapper is 8.0.1 and this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ I've tried the suggested answers without any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the collection property in your `CarDTO` so that it becomes -

```cs
public class CarDTO 
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<PartDTO> Parts { get; set; }   // this one
}
```

Just change it from `IReadOnlyList<Part>` to `IReadOnlyList<PartDTO>` That should solve your problem.

With your current definition of `CarDTO`, the following configuration in your first map -

```cs
.ForMember (dest => dest.Parts, opt =>
                    opt.MapFrom (src => src.CarParts.Select (x => x.Part)));
```

is basically mapping from `Part` to `Part`.

So your second map, from `Part` to `PartDTO`, is not being used at all. Hence `PartId` is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
CreateMap<Car, CarDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add also

```
CreateMap<CarPart, CarPart> ();
CreateMap<Part, Part> ();
```